# Clicking on absolute xpath is not working in Appium BrowserStack

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android, browserstack

When I try running in local it works but in BrowserStack its not working

```
MobileElement el = driver.findElementByXPath("/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup[2]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup[3]/android.widget.Button");
        el.click();
```

Exception is below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had the chance to specify the Appium version(same as your local set up) explicitly using the capability '*browserstack.appium_version*' in your tests?

Reference for the above capability can be found here: https://www.browserstack.com/app-automate/capabilities.

Comment: let me try it also